# How to filter content by taxonomy term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm using Drupal 7 and trying to filter my content based on taxonomy, but it looks like I can only filter based on status and type. Is there a setting or module that would offer more options to filter content by?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Does your all taxonomy terms are under one Vocabulary?

Comment: I have a few vocabularies.

Comment: And actually how to you plan to filter by term? Since there is a couple of possibility. In general this approach is so custom, that I don't think there will be any module for this, but rather you have to write your own to extend this form.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to expose taxonomy term as filter in views. Unfortunately, in Drupal 7, the content list is not built by views.

[Administration Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) is a module which can replace it with the views **Administration: Nodes**.

[image: Views created by Administration Views module]

In the views, you can add ***Content: Has taxonomy term*** filter and expose it. But it only support **ONE** vocabulary.

[image: Content: Has taxonomy term]

How about having a term filter on more then vocabulary? It is quite tricky, but not impossible.

First, add a relationship ***Content: Taxonomy terms on node***, and check the vocabularies. In example, they are `tags` and `topics`.

[image: Content: Taxonomy terms on node]

Then, now you can add filter ***Taxonomy term: Name***, this filter only appear when you added the taxonomy term as relationship.

[image: Taxonomy term: Name]

In ***Operator***, there are many options, you can pick a suitable one for your case. I chose `Contains` in my example.

[image: Operator options]

> **Note:**
>
> With this method, you will have a ordinary text field rather then autocomplete field. It is the only downside.

Comment: "taxonomy term as filter" can you please explain me what will be the searching criteria? Just with words. Because I see too many options.

Comment: Filter **Content: Has taxonomy term (exposed)**. Should be this one?

Comment: But this requires two parameters: vid and a tid. How will the widget look like?: )

Comment: @JimmyKo, `Content: Has taxonomy term` will allow to select from only one vocabulary which we define during its setup. But what about the other taxonomies. This I thought also, but he has more than one vocabulary. If we can select all vocabularies, please let me know, it will be educating, I tried to do that but no luck.

Comment: Let me think it, in fact I answer the question before reading the comments.

Comment: @CodeNext I tried a method. There is no autocomplete but it can filter the content by term name from more then one vocabulary. What do you think?

Comment: @ssibal I can't tag 2 names in one comment....

Comment: @JimmyKo, I did check by downloading that module, It is not giving result from  the other vocabulary. It is giving the result from the vocabulary which we did select in `Content: Has taxonomy term`. Did you achieve some otehr way or I am missing something?

Comment: I am on the way to home now. Will update to the answer today later :)

Comment: @CodeNext  I have updated the answer. Cheers.

Comment: @ssibal  I have updated the answer. Cheers.

Comment: I think, This is a perfect solution..+1