# Exposing New Vocabulary As Filter Drupal 7

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

If I create a new vocabulary with a few items (categories), how can I expose it as a filter on one of  my views?

To be more particular, I have an existing view with some filters already exposed. I would like to add a couple of new vocabularies to it as well as swap an existing vocabulary for a new one.

If it is relevant, I am currently using BEF (Better Exposed Filters) module to expose the current filters.

Comment: Please check my [answer in this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/210483/56904).

Comment: Your answer relies on Administrative Views. I have just tried installing it and it will not enable because it is incompatible with 7.3+ Drupal. I have Drupal 7.43

Comment: It is not depends on that module. I explained in answer that how you can configure the views.

Comment: "In the views, you can add Content: Has taxonomy term filter and expose it. But it only support ONE vocabulary."

Comment: That is the part I am unsure on how to do. Can you show any directions or screenshots?

Comment: You should read the whole answer. I have explained how to make it work for multiple vocabularies. I am on the street right now. I get back you later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43839/discussion-between-jimmy-ko-and-madphysicist).

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Thank you for you help!

Comment: Great to know that.